# How to update dependencies of dependencies using npm

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm very wondered that I can't find an answer to this simple question. Also I'm very wondered that `npm update` does not solve this.

I can't post my complete dependency tree here but let me describe my issue anyway:

minimist is outdated (version 1.2.0) and has a security vulnerability in this version. The packages require minimist define the dependency as ^1.2.0 - so it is compatible with 1.2.2.

The common solution is to put it to `package.json` within `devDependencies` or `dependencies` with `^1.2.2`. I don't want to put it into `package.json`. I feel like `npm update` should also update indirect dependencies.

Am I missing something?

Here you can see my package-lock.json: https://github.com/tflori/riki-community/blob/master/package-lock.json

And the output of `npm ls minimist`:

```
riki-community@ /home/iras/work/projects/riki/community
├─┬ awesome-typescript-loader@5.2.1
│ ├─┬ loader-utils@1.2.3
│ │ └─┬ json5@1.0.1
│ │   └── minimist@1.2.0  deduped
│ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│   └── minimist@0.0.8 
├─┬ jest@25.1.0
│ └─┬ @jest/core@25.1.0
│   ├─┬ @jest/transform@25.1.0
│   │ └─┬ @babel/core@7.8.7
│   │   └─┬ json5@2.1.2
│   │     └── minimist@1.2.5 
│   └─┬ jest-haste-map@25.1.0
│     └─┬ sane@4.1.0
│       ├─┬ @cnakazawa/watch@1.0.4
│       │ └── minimist@1.2.0  deduped
│       └── minimist@1.2.0  deduped
├─┬ node-sass@4.13.1
│ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│   └── minimist@1.2.0 
├─┬ ts-jest@25.2.1
│ └─┬ json5@2.1.2
│   └── minimist@1.2.5 
├─┬ tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
│ └─┬ tsconfig-paths@3.8.0
│   └── minimist@1.2.0  deduped
└─┬ webpack@4.42.0
  └─┬ watchpack@1.6.0
    └─┬ chokidar@2.1.8
      └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@1.2.9
        └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
          ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY mkdirp@0.5.1
          │ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY minimist@0.0.8 
          └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY rc@1.2.8
            └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY minimist@1.2.0
```

Comment: `npm update` should do the trick, unless there is some package that is not aligned with the versions, `npm ls minimist` will list all the packages that dependent on `minimist`

Comment: Since your project is hosted on github you can use  [depend bot](https://dependabot.com/blog/hello-github) for this. It will create automatic PRS

Comment: that is a workaround for a solution that `npm-update` should do, or what you mean? maybe it is a bug from npm-update or it is a missing feature but that is not a regular answer to this question: it does not help others with the same problem not using github...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your best bet is to update npm to version >= 7.0. Please see the answer from xeos for more details. If that is not possible there are two solutions:

---

The problem is the depth. From the documentation:

> As of npm@2.6.1, the npm update will only inspect top-level packages. Prior versions of npm would also recursively inspect all dependencies. To get the old behavior, use npm --depth 9999 update.

So we have to provide the depth that we want to update. In my case, the 9999 depth took too long and I cancelled it. But a `--depth 5` was enough.

```bash
npm update --depth 5
```

---

If that does still not update the dependency then you have to manually change the `package-lock.json`.

Open the `package-lock.json` and find all occurrences of `"minimist": {` and remove the object.

Example:

Change this:

```
      "dependencies": {
        "minimist": {
          "version": "1.2.0",
          "bundled": true,
          "dev": true,
          "optional": true
        }
      }
```

to that:

```
      "dependencies": {
      }
```

And run `npm install` again.

Comment: --depth is no longer available. https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0019-remove-update-depth-option.md

Comment: if there is no --depth option then also dependencies should work. see the answer below from xeos.

Answer (score 22):

As of npm `v7.0.0`, running `npm update` will always update **all packages**, not just the ones specified in root `package.json` file. NPM [has removed](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0019-remove-update-depth-option.md) `--depth` option from `npm update` command and changed its behavior.

*Note: it is still possible that some underlying package is specifying an outdated version as a dependency, which will prevent `npm update` from installing the latest version. You don't have many options, other than forcing a resolution to a more recent version.*

Comment: Great to hear that! Do I understand correct that we still need to remove the dependency solution in package lock? Or is that also fixed in npm 7?

Comment: @iRaS that is fixed as well. Here is the summary from RFC: "`npm update` will always update all nodes in the tree, at every depth. Essentially, make `npm update` equivalent to `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install.`" So `npm update` ignores `package-lock.json`.

Comment: @Xeos How do I _"force a resolution to a more recent version"_? I tried to `npm install` a newer package but the old major version is still there.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter you can use this npm package for it https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions

Answer (score 4):

I also needed to manually change the minimist version to "^1.2.5" from "0.0.8" for the dependency of "mkdirp"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to update all dependencies recursively, I believe this is the fastest, most robust solution:

First, make sure you commit any changes in case you run into problems with `git commit package*.json`. Second, update any of your direct dependencies as desired with `npm outdated` and `npm update xyz`

Now, update all package versions with a clean build of package-lock.json:

```sh
# remove current node_modules/ and package-lock.json
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules/

# rebuild package-lock.json the the semantically-compatible 
# latest package versions & install node_modules/
npm install

# ensure nothing broke
npm test
```

If there is a problem, roll back:

```sh
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules/
git checkout package*.json
npm install
```

P.S. This technique has worked well for me, but I'm always learning more about NPM & package-lock. I'd love to hear from other NPM experts on this technique.

Comment: This is exactly what `npm update` is doing now since npm v7. See [Xeos' post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69950457/865418) & comments for details.