# Want to update nested dependency in npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm

I have 'request' npm package which is deprecated and being installed by another npm package as a dependency. Now I  would like to update the dependencies of request package. I tried every possible way but, didn't find the solution.

Here's the dependency tree which i have to update the last one i.e. **uuid**:

```
`-- protractor@7.0.0
  `-- webdriver-manager@12.1.8
    `-- request@2.88.2
      `-- uuid@3.4.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to updating dependencies of dependencies using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719446/how-to-updating-dependencies-of-dependencies-using-npm)

Comment: 2.88.2 is the latest version of request, and 3.4.0 is the latest version of uuid that meets its requirements: https://github.com/request/request/blob/3c0cddc7c8eb60b470e9519da85896ed7ee0081e/package.json#L49.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM packages are built to work with a certain version (or version set) of their dependencies. If you update `uuid` to a later version, you might run into unexpected issues with `request`. Updating a dependency of one of your dependencies explicitly is not supported or recommended therefore.

Comment: As a workaround add `request` and `uuid` packages to direct dependencies and override `"request": { "uuid": "$uuid"  }},`  version