# How to install newest version of react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs

When executing `npm i -D react-router-dom`, I am alerted to a couple of warnings regarding deprecated packages/dependencies (see the code snippet below). That's why I wanted to install the newest version of `react-router-dom`, but I don't know the correct command for it. Thanks for your help!

```
npm i -D react-router-dom

npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added  

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\WASSIM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-08T12_15_23_618Z-debug.log
```

Comment: npm i react-router-dom

Comment: the `-D` stands for dev dependency, the correct command is `npm i react-router-dom --save` so it saves it to your package.json, check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom, if you want to confirm your command for installation, also I recommend using a more advanced package manager such as `yarn`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to update your npm dependencies.

1. Minor version upgrades
2. Major version upgrades

For minor version upgrades (e.g. from version `1.0.0` to `1.0.5`) you can simply run `npm install`. npm will then run upgrades for all dependencies that are used in the current project path.

In React.js applications, there is a file in your project path named `package.json`. If you want to do a major version upgrade (e.g. from version `1.0.0` to `2.0.0`), you have to open the file and manually change the entry of `react-router-dom`. `package.json` has the following structure:

```
{
   "name": "name"
   "version": "1.0.0"
   ...
   "dependencies": {
      "react-router-dom": "5.3.0"
      ...
   }
}
```

If you want to upgrade for example from version `5.3.0` to `6.0.0`, you would change it to:

```
{
   "name": "name"
   "version": "1.0.0"
   ...
   "dependencies": {
      "react-router-dom": "6.0.0"
      ...
   }
}
```

Sometimes sub-dependencies (i.e. other packages that are used in `react-router-dom`) are deprecated. I would not recommend to update them manually because other dependencies may be dependent on that particular version of a package. If you still want to have a look at it, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719446/how-to-updating-dependencies-of-dependencies-using-npm).